How to enhance security for Azure Functions
This is more of a technical question, so there is no code involved...
I have an Azure Function backend and a web app service that stores a react js web page, I have implemented Azure keys on the Azure Functions, and I am sending them through the headers for better security measures. I have also configured CORS on the Azure Functions to only receive request from my webpage in my web app service.
The problem is that I still can access the function from Postman if I get the url, the data and the Azure key token. I want to let only the webpage to make request and reject all other, in this case I want the it is impossible for Postman to access the backend, it has to be accessible only through the frontend (Azure web app service).
If it is impossible - let me know; but if there is a way to do this, I would love to know how exactly.

Cors only prevents another website from using your API as its backend. It doesn't provide any security.
If someone has access to your key then it's tricky to keep them from using your API. You could try something with a nonce or some other calculated value that is difficult to reverse engineer for someone looking at their network tab. That said, you have to give their client the code to create this so it isn't full proof.
